# How to check my cmake using debug or release?

Tags: cmake

I want to check default cmake build mode.

when i do this:

```
message(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
```

it comes out:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments
```

seems not existed environment variable `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}`.

I also read some blogs, which said, i can:

```
cmake -L . | grep CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
```

to check, but i got:

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=
```

So, how to check my cmake default build mode?

I want to use release mode, but seems

```
cmake ..
```

and

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

make no difference in the messages.

Could you help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *default* is that CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE *is* undefined, which equates to a toolchain-specific implicit default.

Personally I add something like...

```
if ( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
    message( "Build Type not set, defaulting to Debug..." )
    set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
endif()
```

...both to make the default **explicit**, and to default to Debug, as you usually build that much more often than the Release configuration.

Comment: default is release? I read some blogs, which said default is debug ：（

Comment: @nick: Apparently the default is toolchain-specific.... anyway, since I pretty much always set the default explicitly as shown, it does not matter.